# Same width for all list items within an unordered list set to the width of the longest content

Tags: css

Is there a way to do this without the use of JavaScript? If the question is unclear... I have an unordered list which includes several list items their content width are all different. I want all the widths to be set to the longest content width of the list items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the list display to `inline-block` or `table` to make it fit its contents rather than act as a block:

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/yx9Je/2)**

Comment: Since you helped me and I am unsure really when people posted their answered I will pick yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
```

in your CSS class.

Comment: Great, this works perfectly. Thank you.
Edit: Will accept as answer asap, and it seems the width is not necessary.

Comment: @auragar this won't fit to the longest element as you requested, see http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/yx9Je/1/

Comment: @koala_dev Well it seems to have worked for me...? Whoops I see why. I also set ul to display:table. Which works...

Comment: @auragar well it's hard to tell what's happening in your case without any markup and CSS code from your part, anyways it's clear that setting the width of the list items to 100% wouldn't make them all fit to the longest one, unless the display property of the list has been changed

Comment: @auragar I see, well that explains it

Answer (score 1):

Try this html,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        This is sample text.
    </li>
    <li>
        This is sample text.
    </li>
    <li>
        This is sample text.
    </li>
    <li>
        This is sample text with longest content in unordred list.
    </li>
</ul>
```

With CSS,

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

li{
    border:1px solid orange;
    list-style:none;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vxhve/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
li
{
    background:Red;
}
ul
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hWRnZ/10/)